# Windows 10 - Where can I download the latest CBB/Semi-Annual Channel release?

Tags: windows-10, updates

There is a slower update cycle version of Windows 10 called "CBB". "Current Branch for Business". It has been renamed to "Semi-Annual Channel" lately. Point is, this channel updates slower than the "Current Branch".

Now I after some updates I have noticed that I have received the option to switch to CBB. And it worked lovely until I was overly bored one day and updated to Slow ring. Which feels like Fedora Rawhide. (read: fun but unusable for daily work.)

So, I want to do a complete reinstall.
But I want to start with CBB and stay on that update ring / channel.
How do achieve this?

Comment: If you can select the "slow ring" are you sure you are not using an Insider Preview build?

Comment: "How do achieve this?" - Download the ISO for the CBB (1703) and install it

Answer (score 3):

Build 1703 is the current CBB/Semi-Annual release, as of July 11th of 2017. It is also the current "Normal" branch release:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-info.aspx

So, use the System Restore function to go back to whatever you previously had installed, and update it to get to 1703, and you'll be on CBB/SA/Normal.

If you're unable to use the Restore and Recovery features to go back to the normal release cycle, you may have to use the Windows Media Creation Tool to run a manual or clean install: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10